# Windows 98 SE install screen on Virtualbox is a mess, how to fix?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, ms-dos, windows-98

I'm trying to install Windows 98 SE on Virtualbox, but the screen is messed up:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? Or perhaps could there somewhere be a complete guide, which displays every each screen one by one, so I could control the installation by pressing the correct buttons at correct times, without seeing anything? Googling didn't return much.

Why I am doing this: I want to play an old game, but it keeps crashing on my Windows XP at random times. I tried DOSbox as well but the problem remains, so I thought of using the real deal instead. I think it did work on Win98SE before, not sure (it's the only CD I have). Perhaps a DOS installation would be best, but I dont know where to get just that, and not sure if Virtualbox can install it.

**Note:** I have already tried the Windows XP compatibility options in the .exe file, but it does not prevent the random crashing.

I am running Virtualbox from Windows XP SP3 32bit (year old updates)

Comment: Virtualbox has lots of issues with Windows 9x. Try [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24439) instead.

Comment: More information about the host operating system is required.  Its very likely the problem is with Virtualbox which means asking on their community forum might get you an answer faster.

Comment: @Ramhound, i thought i told i use winxp, why the downvote?

Comment: @Rookie - I didn't downvote you.